# Effect of Double Quotation marks on File Path in Powershell

Tags: powershell, double, filepath

The following is a simple code I wrote in Powershell:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.CPU -gt 1} | Sort-Object -Property CPU -Descending |

Select-Object -Property ProcessName,CPU,PM | Export-Csv -Path C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\TaskManager.csv-NoTypeInformation

**$FilePath = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\TaskManager.csv"**
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Workbooks = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($FilePath)
**$Excel.visible = $true**
```

If I lose the double quotation marks in the $FilePath variable, the code will run and open the results in an Excel window in the foreground, even without the $Excel.visible = $true line, but it will generate an error message AFTER it has successfully opened the file saying
"Sorry, we couldn't find . Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?"

If I keep the double quotation marks, but don't include $Excel.visible = $true, then the process will only open in the background.

Can anyone please kindly explain to me:

1. Do we need double quotation marks when we assign a variable to a file path?
2. Why does the file open automatically in Excel when no double quotation marks are used? If this is a more efficient code to achieve the same outcome, then why does the red error message pop up?

Thank you very much for your help.[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQUtr.png)

Comment: Yes, you need double (or single) quotation marks in this line: `$FilePath = "C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\TaskManager.csv"`. PowerShell will normally output an error message, if you don't. Unless you suppress any error message using `$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'` (very bad practice!).

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Excel is brought to the foreground automatically because of the error

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, thank you so much for your reply. Can I please ask why Excel is brought to the foreground automatically as a result of not having double quotation marks in the $FilePath variable?

Comment: Thanks for your reply as well zett42 :-)